# Relationship between frobenius norm and operator norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Recently I found in a paper,

$ (1/p)*trace(\Omega \Sigma) = (1/p)|\Omega \Sigma|_{F}^{2} <= |\Omega|_{\infty}^{2}|\Sigma|_{\infty}^{2} <= (trace(\Omega))^{2}|\Sigma|_{\infty}^{2}$.

$\Omega$ and $\Sigma$ are positive definite matrices. p is the number of variables.

How can these inequalities happen? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use Latex.

Comment: I have just edited a question of your. Could you please look the edit and do the same here?

Comment: Is really trace of a matrix equal to its squared Frobenius norm? I don't think so.

Comment: Actually should not the first "equality" be an inequality like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513356/jensens-inequality-for-frobenius-norm with $\Sigma$ replaced by $\Omega\Sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Consider $\Omega=\pmatrix{5&2\\ 2&1}$ and $\Sigma=I$. Then the statement becomes
$$
\frac1p\operatorname{trace}(\Omega)
= \frac1p|\Omega|_{F}^{2}
\le |\Omega|_{\infty}^{2}
\le (\operatorname{trace}(\Omega))^{2},\tag{1}
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac6p \color{red}{=} \frac{34}p \le 49 \color{red}{\le} 36.\tag{2}
$$
Regardless of what $p$ means, $(2)$ is not true.